# How to compare a character or two to another character or two

Tags: java, string, if-statement, char

I've written a for-loop that iterates through a large string and its goal is to see if my string has characters like $ or $$.
This is the if statement that I have inside my for-loop:

```
if (stringName.charAt(i) == "$" || stringName.charAt(i) == "$$")
```

When I compile my code, I get an error saying "incomparable types: char and String" which is self explanatory.
Now my question is, what is the best way to fix it? What method apart from charAt() can I use to compare the two characters string "$$"?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate altogether? Why not check `stringName.contains("$")`?

Comment: Then please explain the actual problem so we can discuss an actual solution.

Comment: Isn't just checking for `'$'` enough? Note that you need single quotes (a `char`) not double quotes (a `String`)

Comment: You may also find [`indexOf('$')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use String.substring() instead. You could rewrite your code like this:

```
if (stringName.charAt(i) == '$' || stringName.substring(i, i + 2).equals("$$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Single character cannot be compared with two. Besides syntactical problems, hard to imagine sense.

You code changed in two places:
Single apostrophe for Char type , and String selection (by `substring()`and comparison (by `equals()`) in his API

```
if (stringName.charAt(i) == '$' || stringName.substring(i,i+2).equals("$$"))
```

EDIT
agree, second condition is superfluous with first, lets understand question

```
 if (stringName.charAt(i) == 'A' || stringName.substring(i,i+2).equals("BB"))
```

Thanks for comment

Comment: Method name is `substring()`. `endIndex` is exclusive. The two conditions are redundant.

Comment: `endIndex` is not inclusive.  You need `i+2`

Comment: thanks for comment, changed

Comment: You missed "Method name is `substring()`" ... not `subString()`.